# Undefined index: post from textarea

Tags: php

After sending, an error always flies to me `Undefined index: post` what to do? help please

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $description = htmlspecialchars($_POST['post']); 
}



<form action="sell.php" method="POST" name="confirmationForm">
 <textarea placeholder="Post your Comment Here ..." form="confirmationForm" name="post" class="form-control custom-control" rows="3" style="resize:none"></textarea>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Request">
</form>
```

Comment: Why you don't check if post is set ? `if(isset($_POST['post'])){`

Comment: If the `<textarea>` is empty it's not submitted with the form **at all** - so it's quite possible for `$_POST['submit']` to be set but **not** `$_POST['post']` - same goes for checkboxes and radio buttons.

Comment: @CD001 not true, empty textareas and text input fields submit an empty string. What you are saying, is only the case for checkboxes / radio buttons, those don’t cause an entry in the form submission data set if not checked.

Comment: The textarea value does not get send with the rest of your form data, because you associated it with a non-existing form reference, `form="confirmationForm"` - the value of this attribute must contain the **ID** of a form element.

Comment: @04FS - try it.

Comment: @CD001 that it doesn’t submit _any_ value here in this particular instance, is due to the `form` attribute mismatch. That does not change anything about the rest of what I said - empty textareas and empty text input fields submit an empty string.

Comment: @04FS ... oooh, I swear it never used to get submitted O_o I've been working on the assumption that checkboxes, radio buttons and textareas don't get submitted, when empty, for like... years! I do apologise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `form="confirmationForm"` from textarea.
Try this

```
<textarea placeholder="Post your Comment Here ..."  name="post" class="form-control custom-control" rows="3" style="resize:none"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 3):

While using `form` attribute in form elements, the `id` attribute of form should be same as `form` attribute of form elements. Like:

```
<form action="sell.php" method="POST" id="confirmationForm">
    <textarea placeholder="Post your Comment Here ..." form="confirmationForm" name="post" class="form-control custom-control" rows="3" style="resize:none"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Request">
</form>
```

Or remove `form` attribute from textarea.

Answer (score 1):

The textarea value does not get send with the rest of your form data, because you associated it with a non-existing form reference, `form="confirmationForm"` - the value of this attribute must contain the **ID** of a form element.

Your form only has `name="confirmationForm"`.

Add an id, or remove the `form` attrribute from the textarea.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code...

```
<form action="sell.php" method="POST" id="confirmationForm">
<textarea placeholder="Post your Comment Here ..." name="post" class="form-control 
custom-control" rows="3" style="resize:none"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Request">
</form>
```